# How to style multiple components at the same time from outside in react-native?

Tags: react-native

First, that's what I'm trying to accomplish:

[Tree cards, with different background color and different text color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtDmQ.png)

I've created the first card and was thinking about use it as base. So that's the code:

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width

const Testemonial1 = (props) => {

```
return (
    <Card style={{ ...styles.card1, ...props.style }}>
        <View style={{...styles.messageContainer, ...props.style }}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={props.source} />
            <View style = {{...styles.textContainer, ...props.style }}>
                <BFwBasicText style={{...styles.text, ...props.style }}>{props.message}</BFwBasicText>
                <Subtitle style={{...styles.subtitle, ...props.style }}>{props.name}</Subtitle>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Card>
)
```

}

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
card1: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.BFOrange,
    marginVertical: "2%",
    width: screenWidth > 600 ? "70%" : "80%",
    marginHorizontal: screenWidth > 600 ? "10%" : "5%",
    alignSelf: "flex-start"
},
messageContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
},
image: {
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: screenWidth < 350 ? 70 : screenWidth > 500 ? 110 : 80,
    height: screenWidth < 350 ? 70 : screenWidth > 500 ? 110 : 80,
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginLeft: screenWidth > 600 ? "3%" : 0,

},
textContainer:{
    width: "95%"
},
text: {
    marginTop: "3%",
    width: "75%",
    overflow: "hidden",
},
subtitle: {
    fontSize: screenWidth < 350 ? 18 : screenWidth > 600 ? 32 : 20,
    marginLeft: "5%"
},
```

})

and that's the code for the 3rd card (it should change only colors but keep measures):

```
import Testemonial1 from './Testemonial1'
```

const Testemonial3 = (props) => {

```
return (
    <Testemonial1
        source={props.source}
        name={props.name}
        message={props.message}
        style = {{...styles.card1, ...styles.subtitle, ...styles.testemonialText}}/>
)
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

```
card1: {
 backgroundColor: Colors.BFYellow,
},

subtitle: {
   color: Colors.BFOrange
},

testemonialText:{
    color: "white",
}
```

})

With this code, I get the updated background color and text color.

However, the "subtitle" style that should be orange is getting the same color of "testemonialText" and although the background color changes, it looks like the measures are changing too, even though it shouldn't.

That's the result I'm getting:

[the 3rd card is not respecting the styles coming from outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Z3g.png)

Does anybody have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I've lost 2 days on this and could not find a solution other than copy the whole code for "Testemonial3" and only adjust the lines I need, what I believe is not the best practice.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me any insight.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your subtitle tag

```
<Subtitle style={{...styles.subtitle, ...props.style }}>{props.name}</Subtitle>
```

is overwriting the subtitle style with the props style.

Your props style

```
style = {{...styles.card1, ...styles.subtitle, ...styles.testemonialText}}
```

overwrites your subtitle style with testimonialText style.
That's why you're seeing this behavior.

Just change

```
<Subtitle style={{...styles.subtitle, ...props.style }}>{props.name}</Subtitle>` to `<Subtitle style={{...styles.subtitle}}>{props.name}</Subtitle>
```